# How do I get my sort function to call a comparison function

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, sorting

Trying to write some clean JS sort functions. Below is a click handler on a button in my template, it calls the individual methods to sort by different properties.

`(click)="addresses.sort(sortByTown)"`

Which calls the method below. It works great which is nice!

```
sortByTown(address1: any, address2: any): number {
    const a = address1.town.toUpperCase();
    const b = address2.town.toUpperCase();
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

The problem I'm having, is that I've got about 4 of these sort methods, and I'd like to put the if statements into their own function for getting better at writing DRY code. So I've tried the below approach, but the compareFunction never even get's called. What am I doing wrong?

```
sortByTown(address1: any, address2: any): number {
    const a = address1.town.toUpperCase();
    const b = address2.town.toUpperCase();
    return this.compareAddresses(a, b);
  }

  compareAddresses(a: string | number, b: string | number): number {
    if (a > b) {
      return 1;
    } else if (a < b) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 0;
  }
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'compareAddresses' of undefined
    at sortByStreetName (address.component.ts:43)
    at Array.sort (<anonymous>)
    at AddressComponent_Template_button_click_9_listener (address.component.html:10)
    at executeListenerWithErrorHandling (core.js:15182)
    at wrapListenerIn_markDirtyAndPreventDefault (core.js:15217)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:582)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:406)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:28500)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:405)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:178)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably using `this` inside the callback that's defined as a plain JS function is running into scoping issues.

Try to define `sortByTown()` as an arrow function.

```js
sortByTown = (address1: any, address2: any): number => {
  const a = address1.town.toUpperCase();
  const b = address2.town.toUpperCase();
  return this.compareAddresses(a, b);
}
```

Update: As pointed out by @yurzui in the comments, defining `compareAddresses()` as an plain JS function wouldn't change the behaviour as it doesn't depend on member variables.

Comment: I think arrow function for `sortByTown` method is enough here

Comment: Amazing! Worked like a charm and learnt something new. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @yurzui: You're right, there is no usage of `this` in `compareAddresses`.